# Same punishment or different punishments? Luke 12:42-48 vs Luke 13:1-5

Tags: luke, contradiction, sin, soteriology, morality

Luke 12:42-48 (NIV) seems to support different degrees of punishment:

> 42 The Lord answered, “Who then is the faithful and wise manager, whom the master puts in charge of his servants to give them their food allowance at the proper time? 43 It will be good for that servant whom the master finds doing so when he returns. 44 Truly I tell you, he will put him in charge of all his possessions. 45 But suppose the servant says to himself, ‘My master is taking a long time in coming,’ and he then begins to beat the other servants, both men and women, and to eat and drink and get drunk. 46 The master of that servant will come on a day when he does not expect him and at an hour he is not aware of. He will cut him to pieces and assign him a place with the unbelievers.
>
> **47 “The servant who knows the master’s will and does not get ready or does not do what the master wants will be beaten with many blows. 48 But the one who does not know and does things deserving punishment will be beaten with few blows. From everyone who has been given much, much will be demanded; and from the one who has been entrusted with much, much more will be asked**.

However, Luke 13:1-5 (NIV) seems to say otherwise:

> Now there were some present at that time who told Jesus about the Galileans whose blood Pilate had mixed with their sacrifices. 2 Jesus answered, **“Do you think that these Galileans were worse sinners than all the other Galileans because they suffered this way? 3 I tell you, no!** **But unless you repent, you too will all perish**. 4 Or those eighteen who died when the tower in Siloam fell on them—**do you think they were more guilty than all the others living in Jerusalem? 5 I tell you, no! But unless you repent, you too will all perish**.”

Are all sinners equally guilty and deserving of the same punishment, or are there different degrees of guilt that justify proportional punishments on a case-by-case basis?

Answer (score 1):

The two passages in Luke 12 vs Luke 13 are discussing two separate matters and thus, should not be confused.

In **Luke 13:1-5**, Jesus is discussing the common myth (at the time) that what people suffered in this life was a consequence of their moral standing with God.  Jesus was at pains to debunk this idea on other occasions as well such as Luke 9:1-3 -

> Now as Jesus was passing by, He saw a man blind from birth, and His
> disciples asked Him, “Rabbi, who sinned, this man or his parents, that
> he was born blind?” Jesus answered, “Neither this man nor his parents
> sinned, but this happened so that the works of God would be displayed
> in him.

Thus, in Luke 13:1-5, Jesus is saying that the Galileans and the 18 on whom the tower fell, not not suffer these things because they were especially sinful.  The entire book of Job takes up this theme.

By complete contrast, **Luke 12:42-48** is discussing final punishment of the wicked as is clear from his discussion in the previous few verses of Jesus' servants being ready for the second coming of the Master.  James takes up this theme as well in James 3:1 -

> Not many of you should become teachers, my fellow believers, because
> you know that we who teach will be judged more strictly.

That is, those who represent Jesus and His teaching to others are judged by a higher standard.  Jesus spells this out in Luke 12:42-48 where wicked teachers will be judged more strictly that the wicked who were not teachers - the reason is made clear - the teachers were better informed and should have known better.

The parable of the talents (Matt 25:14-28) appears to teach the same truth - the one who had been given much - much was required.  In this case, the one given least (one talent), the least was required but even he failed to do anything.  Again, this parable is not discussing our daily lives so much as our final destiny based on what we do with the opportunities we are given.

Again, Jesus discusses this matter in Matt 7:21-23 where He says:

> Not everyone who says to Me, ‘Lord, Lord,’ will enter the kingdom of
> heaven, but only he who does the will of My Father in heaven. Many
> will say to Me on that day, ‘Lord, Lord, did we not prophesy in Your
> name, and in Your name drive out demons and perform many miracles?’
> Then I will tell them plainly, ‘I never knew you; depart from Me, you
> workers of lawlessness!’

Thus, the teachers will be judged most severely.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to realize that Jesus' reign is in heaven, not on earth. His teaching referred to a time in the End Times, and there is only one punishment, the 2nd death described in Revelation 20:11-15, of which Jesus meant in Luke 13:1-5.

But Luke 12:42-46 is talking about Watchfulness. Unlike Luke 13:1-5, all servants in this parable refer only to Jesus believers, or Christian today. Luke 12:47-48 is an extrapolation followed the parable, but not part of the parable. The servant in the parable received punishment of 2nd death, same punishment as Luke 13:1-5, as we see it said;

> 46 The master of that servant will come on a day when he does not expect him and at an hour he is not aware of. He will cut him to pieces and **assign him a place with the unbelievers.**

Now let's take a look at Luke 12:47-48

> 47 “The servant who knows the master’s will and does not get ready or does not do what the master wants **will be beaten with many blows**.
>
> 48 But the one who does not know and does things deserving punishment **will be beaten with few blows.** From everyone who has been given much, much will be demanded; and from the one who has been entrusted with much, much more will be asked. (Luke 12:47-48 NIV)

Compare it to Paul wrote in 1 Corinthians 3:10-15. The italic words in bracket is my added explanation.

> 10 By the grace God has given me, I laid a foundation as a wise builder, and someone else is building on it. But each one should build **with care** (*means watchfulness*).
>
> 11 For no one can lay any foundation other than the one already laid, which is Jesus Christ.
>
> 12 If anyone builds on this foundation using gold, silver, costly stones, wood, hay or straw,
>
> 13 their work will be shown for what it is, because the Day will bring it to light. It will be revealed with fire, and the fire will test the quality of each person’s work.
>
> 14 **If what has been built survives, the builder will receive a reward.**
>
> 15 **If it is burned up, the builder will suffer loss but yet will be saved—even though only as one escaping through the flames.**

The statement in Luke 12:48; "**From everyone who has been given much, much will be demanded; and from the one who has been entrusted with much, much more will be asked.**", refers to the judgement whether the work of the servant is up to expectation according to their ability. If the work is good (survives), they receive a reward (1 Cor 3:14), if it is poorly done, they suffer loss and some will loss more (beaten with many blows), some will loss less (beaten with few blows), though they will be saved but is like escaping through the flames (1 Cor 3:15).